# Angularjs : ng-class not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive, ng-class

i'm using animate.css

**HTML**

```
    <div ng-init="animate=false" when-visible="animate=true" ng-class="{animate: visible}">
  <h3 class="section-title" ng-class="{animate: fadeIn}">{{titresection}}</h3>
</div>
```

but not working when i scroll any idea ?

Comment: try this  <h3  ng-class="{'fadeIn': animate == true}">{{titresection}}</h3>

Comment: @hadiJZ i get error in my console Directive: angular-scroll-animate 'when-visible' attribute must specify a function. and not display value (titiresection)

Comment: do you inject angular-scroll-animate dependency?

Comment: @hadiJZ yes i already inject !

Answer (score 0):

Just checked the when-visible directive, in your controller, you need to create a function on your scope, and then reference that in the *when-visible* directive.

Controller:

```
$scope.showSection = function(){
    $scope.animate = true;
}
```

Page:

```
<div ng-init="animate=false" when-visible="showSection" ng-class="{'visible': animate}">
    <h3 class="section-title" ng-class="{'fadeIn': animate}">{{titresection}}</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: create a plunkr or something then.